# setState doesn't update nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my componentDidUpdate I want to change the state of my nested object but It doesn't work.

I did exactly as I did in componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps but still nothing.

Here's my state :

```
this.state = {
    timer: {
       seconds: 0,
       minutes: 0,
       hours: 0
    },
    counter: 30,
    intervalId : null
}
```

Here's the code that works :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        var newTimer = { ...this.state.timer };
        newTimer.seconds++;
        this.setState({ timer : newTimer });
    }, 100);
    this.setState({
        intervalId : intervalId
    });
}
```

Here's the code that doesn't work :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { seconds, minutes, hours } = this.state.timer;
    const { counterHit } = this.props;
    const newTimer = { ...this.state.timer };

    if (seconds > 0 && seconds % 30 === 0) { counterHit(); }

    if (seconds >= 60) {
        newTimer.minutes++;
        newTimer.seconds = 0;

        console.log("our new obj : ", newTimer);
        console.log("Before state update: ", this.state.timer);

        this.setState({ timer : newTimer }, () => {
            console.log("After state update: ", this.state.timer);
        });
    } else if (minutes >= 60) {
        newTimer.hours++;
        this.setState({ timer : newTimer } );
    }
}
```

The console.log()s print the following:

```
our new obj :  {seconds: 0, minutes: 1, hours: 0}
Before state update:  {seconds: 60, minutes: 0, hours: 0}
After state update:  {seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0}
```

As you can see the minutes didn't update.

Comment: I believe it's because you're setting a value `newTimer` on state. Try: `this.setState({ timer: newTimer})`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: One thing that's quite confusing; why are you updating the timer in both `componentDidUpdate` and in an interval set in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Also, it does seem to be working? https://codesandbox.io/s/kl438mopv

Comment: I restarted the build and It works now. weird. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is:

```
 this.setState({ newTimer });
```

What that means is:

```
this.setState({ 
    newTimer: newTimer
});
```

But because you want to update the `timer` field, use this:

```
this.setState({ 
    timer: newTimer
});
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that, but It's not the problem; it still doesn't work

Comment: @AbdellahSAQ Can you please create a codepen? and share the whole code? https://codepen.io/

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know how to make it work in codepen but here's my whole code : https://codepen.io/Neferest/pen/BObQdz?editors=1010

Comment: @AbdellahSAQ `counterHit()` is missing. You can try posting the whole project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: It works now I only had to restart react-script. thanks a lot for your time :D